# Does the category of finite stochastic maps hold the empty set?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, category-theory

I am a little confused about the definition of the category $\text{FinStoch}$ of finite stochastic maps. [Tobias, page 13](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.07021) defines $\text{FinStoch}$ as having objects as finite sets and arrows as stochastic matrices. Presumably this means that the empty set $0$ is an object of $\text{FinStoch}.$ An idea reinforced by Tobias's claim that there is an inclusion functor from $\text{FinSet}$ to $\text{FinStoch}$. Am I understanding this right ? And is $0$ an initial object of $\text{FinStoch}$ in this case ?

On the other hand [Fong, page 27](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.6201) defines $\text{FinStoch}$ as the category with objects as finite measurable spaces, and arrows as stochastic maps. In this case, I guess that the empty set is not an object. In particular [Preston, page 3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.3066.pdf) says that a measurable space has to be non-empty (is this forced ?).

Basically my questions are: (A) Am I understanding theses definitions properly ?, and (B) which definition of $\text{FinStoch}$ is preferable ?

Comment: The empty set can be made into a measurable space in a unique way, but there is no way to put a probability measure on it. I think it would be preferable to permit the empty measurable space.

Comment: Thanks. And if we permit it, then would it be an initial object ?

Answer (score 1):

By default I would say the empty set is included, since the empty set is a finite set, and if it wasn't meant to be included the author would say.

Assuming it's included then indeed it's an initial object, for the same sort of reason that the empty set is an initial object of $\mathsf{Set}$. A markov kernel from a finite set $X$ to a finite set $Y$ can be regarded as a function that takes elements of $X$ and returns probability distributions over $Y$. Much like in $\mathsf{Set}$, since there are no elements of $\emptyset$, a Markov kernel $\
\emptyset\to Y$ can only be the "absurd" function, which would return a probability distribution over $Y$ if only you could give it an element of $\emptyset$, but you can't. Such functions are considered to be unique in category theory, so $\emptyset$ is an initial object of $\mathsf{FinStoch}$.